# Правильно ли я понимаю @Transactional(readOnly = true)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transaction, readonly

Если наш метод помечен аннотацией @Transactional(readOnly = true), то мы не можем в нём (и в тех, методах, которые он вызывает) использовать операции CREAT, UPDATE, DELETE. Но с самими данными после выхода из метода, мы можем делать что угодно? Это правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Моё понимание правильно.
Тем, кто хочет изучить этот вопрос самостоятельно - книга "Spring in action 3 издание". Глава о Транзакциях. 314 стр. Параграф 7.4.1 readOnly.